# Count number of rows when row contains certain text

Tags: python, pandas, string

Probably a simple question but I could not find a simple answer. Let's for example take the following column Status within a dataframe df1:

```
**Status**
Planned
Unplanned
Missing
Corrected
```

I would like to count the rows when a cell contains, Planned and Missing. I tried the following:

```
test1 = df1['Status'].str.contains('Planned|Missing').value_counts()
```

The column Status is from the type: object. What's wrong with my line of code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just filter the df with your boolean condition and then call `len`:

```
In [155]:
len(df[df['Status'].str.contains('Planned|Missing')])

Out[155]:
2
```

Or use the index `True` from your `value_counts`:

```
In [158]:   
df['Status'].str.contains('Planned|Missing').value_counts()[True]

Out[158]:
2
```

Answer (score 3):

[`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) when coupled with `na=False` guarantees you have a Boolean series. Note also `True` / `False` act like `1` / `0` with numeric computations. You can now use [`pd.Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html) directly:

```
count = df['Status'].str.contains('Planned|Missing', na=False).sum()
```

This avoids unnecessary and expensive dataframe indexing operations.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the following one:

```py
df["Status"].value_counts()[['Planned','Missing']].sum()
```

Comment: Please, it is always beneficial to include some context explaining the source code