# calculate the number of rows in a column that meet certain criteria (specific word and empty rows) by using Panda

Tags: pandas, csv, sum, csvreader, emptydatatext

From data in a csv file, I try to obtain using Panda, the sum of the rows of a specific column ("Status_Issue") of the csv file that are:

- empty rows
  and
- rows containing the word "Pending".

Here is the code I used but unfortunately it doesn't work, can you please help me to correct my error.

```
def count_pending_TaxRegulatory():
df = pd.read_csv("sortdata.csv", header=1)
count1 = (df["Status_Issue"]=="Pending").sum()
count2 = df["Status_Issue"].isna().sum()
result1 = count1 + count2
```

Comment: What is the error message? Update your post with the output of `print(df.head().to_string())` or `print(df.head().to_dict())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sum() function return the sum of the values for the requested axis, so unless "Status_Issue" is only either 1 or 0 (where isna is making things 1 or 0 thus working), it won't work as you wanted. check this out
[Count number of rows when row contains certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583151/count-number-of-rows-when-row-contains-certain-text)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that helps me to fix my problem.